# How to solve Tensorflow object detection error

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection

Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Users\dhrub\BDSLP-REALTIME\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py”, line 31, in
from object_detection import model_lib_v2
File “C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py”, line 31, in
from object_detection import model_lib
File “C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib.py”, line 35, in
from object_detection.builders import optimizer_builder
File “C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\optimizer_builder.py”, line 25, in
from official.modeling.optimization import ema_optimizer
File “C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\official\modeling\optimization_init_.py”, line 23, in
from official.modeling.optimization.optimizer_factory import OptimizerFactory
File “C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\official\modeling\optimization\optimizer_factory.py”, line 20, in
import tensorflow_addons.optimizers as tfa_optimizers
File “C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons_init_.py”, line 22, in
from tensorflow_addons import callbacks
File “C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\callbacks_init_.py”, line 17, in
from tensorflow_addons.callbacks.average_model_checkpoint import AverageModelCheckpoint
File “C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\callbacks\average_model_checkpoint.py”, line 17, in
from typeguard import typechecked
File “C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typeguard_init_.py”, line 4, in
from ._checkers import TypeCheckerCallable as TypeCheckerCallable
File “C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typeguard_checkers.py”, line 68, in
from typing_extensions import Any as SubclassableAny
ImportError: cannot import name ‘Any’ from ‘typing_extensions’ (C:\Users\dhrub\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)

I am getting this error while training the data but I have installed everything correctly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello from author here.

Install Anaconda3-2021.11-Windows-x86_64.exe from https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/ 

Latest anaconda version doesn't support.